# In Groovy -How to fill empty fields in version with number zero?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a version like below and I want to add zero (0) in versionB after 2 decimal. How can I achieve this in groovy?

```
versionA=1.12.14
versionB=1.11
```

**Expected OutPut:-**

```
versionA=1.12.14
VersionB=1.11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The term you are are looking for is Semantic Versioning ( semver ).  This is not the prettiest solution but it will work

```
//def semver = "1"
def semver = "1.13"

def split = semver.split("\\.");
if(split.size() == 1) {
    semver+=".0.0"
} else if(split.size()==2) {
    semver+=".0"
}

println semver
```

> In your example you have the variables typed as numbers but they must be strings

Answer (score 1):

A generic variant for version strings of variable lengths:

```
String getFormattedVersion( String raw, int maxPositions = 3 ){
  def parts = raw.split( /\./ )
  (0..<maxPositions).collect{ it < parts.size() ? parts[ it ] : '0' }.join '.'
}

assert '1.2.3' == getFormattedVersion( '1.2.3' )
assert '1.2.0' == getFormattedVersion( '1.2' )
assert '1.0.0' == getFormattedVersion( '1' )
assert '1.2.3.0.0' == getFormattedVersion( '1.2.3', 5 )
```